# Why does GetProcessImageFileName return null instead of the address of the process?

Tags: c++, winapi, qt5

I am trying  to pool the list of all processes in Qt.For this purpose i am using Windows API.
the following code demonstrates my effort so far:

```
QList<QString> frmProcess::GetAllRunningProcesses()
{
    HANDLE hSysSnapshot = NULL;
    HANDLE processHandle;
    PROCESSENTRY32 proc;


    proc.dwSize = sizeof(proc);
    hSysSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot ( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0 );
    Process32First(hSysSnapshot,&proc);
    proc.dwSize = sizeof(proc);

    ui->listWidget->clear();
    LPWSTR processPath;
    list.clear();
    do
    {
        //This block of code is to get each process's path and store it in a list
        //PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS is commented out since it fails the program on start-up

        processHandle = OpenProcess( /*PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS*/PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
                                PROCESS_VM_READ,
                                FALSE, proc.th32ProcessID );

        GetProcessImageFileName(processHandle,processPath,MAX_PATH);
        procpaths.append(QString::fromWCharArray(processPath));

        list.append(QString::fromWCharArray(proc.szExeFile));

    } while(Process32Next(hSysSnapshot,&proc));

    CloseHandle( hSysSnapshot );
    return list;
}
```

In the code posted above, I am trying to get as much as information i can get on a process, for this i am pooling the process names with the help of `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` and then get their path with `GetProcessImageFileName`. And all of this happen in a timer tick event each milliseconds.
If i run the program , after couple of seconds it crashes, I get segmentation fault.
I also tried debugging since i couldn't get any path relating to any process!
And to my surprise i only get empty strings for path of each process!
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GetProcessImageFileName` does not receive a proper argument. `processPath` has to point to valid buffer.

```
TCHAR processPath[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
GetProcessImageFileName(processHandle, processPath, _countof(processPath));
```

Also, you want to check returned value to see if you succeeded or not.

Comment: I tried LPWSTR processPath[MAX_PATH] but it gave compile time errors! stating #####################################                          
error: cannot convert 'WCHAR** {aka wchar_t**}' to 'LPWSTR {aka wchar_t*}' for argument '2' to 'DWORD GetProcessImageFileNameW(HANDLE, LPWSTR, DWORD)'
         GetProcessImageFileName(processHandle,processPath,MAX_PATH);
                                                                   ^

Comment: though your solution works just fine.What if the names are unicode, TCHAR wont be able to store them right?

Comment: `TCHAR` is a proper match to `GetProcessImageFileName`. If you want to use `WCHAR` (for a reason I am not aware of), then you use it with `GetProcessImageFileNameW`.

Comment: Thanks alot, i am dealing with processes in a Unicode environment, so WCHAR would be a better candidate since it supports Unicode characters such as this:سلام thats why i am using this

Comment: Uhhng. Don't use MAX_PATH, this isn't 1995 anymore. A filename can be up to 32768 characters long (in the native representation). If you are in a leaf function then just use a stack buffer of that size. Otherwise allocate a buffer of that size dynamically, and copy it to a shorter buffer if you need to keep it around and don't want to waste 32KB of memory.